General Guidance on How to Copy One Database Row to Another Using Razor Pages
I have an app where the user would like to be able to enter a record for a client and then copy that record to another client. I'm picturing doing this after the record is created and saved. Perhaps from the index page where update and delete buttons already exist for each record. I could add a copy button there. Also thinking of a "save & duplicate" button on the create page itself or even an "update & duplicate" button on the Edit page.
What I would like to have the Copy Button do is to open the record like Edit would, but be able to select a new client ID (while retaining the rest of the same info). For example, let's say two people have the same address info. The user would create Client A with the address and save that record. Then the user would click Copy next to Client A on the Index page and it would open a new record already populated with the same address. The user would just need to select another client's ID from the dropdown list of clients, and then submit to save the new record under the newly selected ID. Client A's record would still be unaffected (ie, I don't want to replace the ID with another one, I want to duplicate the record with a different client.)
Is this something best done with html and c# or maybe javascript? I'm not sure I am using the right key words to search for this as I have not had any success. Ideas?
Here is what I have tried so far: I copied my Edit.cshtml page and Edit.cs and renamed them Copy.cshtml and Copy.cs. I then added a Copy button to my Index page. Then I changed the Post part of my Copy.cs from updating the database to adding (the same as the Create.cs).
Now I can click on the Copy button on my Index page and navigate to the particular record that I want to copy. I can change the Client dropdown to select another client. However when I click the Submit Copy button to bind the new record to the database, I get this error:
SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Client' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
Can someone explain what I need to do differently please. I may be out in left field on this one, but it seems to make sense you could copy by doing something like this, but maybe not? Thanks!!

Well, I'm not sure if this is the right way to go about things, but what I needed to do to make this work is to take the "input hidden asp-for="Client.ClientId"" off of my Copy.cshtml page and then everything worked! I was most of the way there with what I had above.
